# Is it possible to make an image move with the cursor when the cursor reaches the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am creating a game, based off of an image moving with the cursor. I don't want the player to be able to cheat by moving the mouse outside of the box, and then moving the mouse to the finish. If using the setup I have currently, the image will move to where my mouse is. Any idea?

Code:

```js
  

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

```css
    * {cursor: none;}
#image{
position:absolute;
width:25px;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>      
    <img id="image" src="http://static.micheljansen.org/uploads/mac-osx-arrow-cursor.png"/>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3x7cgLdr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that is what you want, but I think it will help.

I defined `var startMove` which will be `false` when the cursor leave the document and will not be `true` until the mouse near by 50 to the image and then the image will start move. https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/3x7cgLdr/2/

```
var startMove;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var difLeft = $('#image').offset().left - e.pageX;
    var difTop = $('#image').offset().top - e.pageY;
    if(difLeft < 50 && difLeft > -50 && difTop < 50 && difTop > -50 ){
      startMove = true;
    }
    if(startMove){
        $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    }
        checkCursor();
});

$(document).mouseleave(function(){
    startMove = false;
})

function checkCursor(){
    if(startMove){$('html').removeClass('showCursor');}
  else{$('html').addClass('showCursor');}
}
```

This added into the whole code:

```js
  

 var startMove;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var difLeft = $('#image').offset().left - e.pageX;
    var difTop = $('#image').offset().top - e.pageY;
    if(difLeft < 10 && difLeft > -10 && difTop < 10 && difTop > -10 ){
      startMove = true;
    }
    if(startMove){
     $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    }
  checkCursor();
});

$(document).mouseleave(function(){
    startMove = false;
})

function checkCursor(){
 if(startMove){$('html').removeClass('showCursor');}
  else{$('html').addClass('showCursor');}
}
```

```css
    html {cursor: none;}
html.showCursor{cursor: default;}
#image{
position:absolute;
width:25px;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>      
    <img id="image" src="http://static.micheljansen.org/uploads/mac-osx-arrow-cursor.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could trigger a cheat event if the cursor moves too far in one go, so:

```
var x=1, y=1, percentAway=30; // start position of cursor...

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if(e.pageX > x*(1+(percentAway/100)) || e.pageX < x*(1-(percentAway/100)) || e.pageY > y*(1+(percentAway/100)) || e.pageY < y*(1-(percentAway/100))) {
        // cheater! greater than 5% away from its last position
        // do something bad to them!
        console.log('cheater: '+x+'-'+y);
    } else {
       // not a cheater, probably
       x = e.pageX; y = e.pageY;
       $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    }
});

// click to set the start position... replace this in your code with the space they should start
$(document).click(function(e) {
  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY;
  console.log(x + '-' + y);
});
```

You might want to go less (1-2%) if two parts of the maze (or whatever) can be quite close, but too small and this might not work well for a quick game.

edit: JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/3x7cgLdr/22/

Here I added in the code and added a bit so you can click to set the initial coordinates - the main problem I guess is that if you move too fast it doesnt update fast enough...

You could also define the areas of the div you want the cursor to be in and just label them as a cheater if they move outside of the area...